# How to open NightShift in display & brightness Programically in iOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, screen

I want to launch NightShift when I touch a button in my app.

I am aware that settings app can be opened by navigating to the settings URL

`UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)`

Is there a link to NightShift too?

If NightShift does not work,is there a way to display & brightness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't navigate to any other page within the iOS Settings app from iOS 10 onwards.

Previously, there used be "prefs:" and "App Prefs:" which could navigate our app within the iOS settings app. But iOS 10 onwards, its a private API and can lead to app rejection by Apple.